# Account and contact soql query

Tags: apex, soql

I want to retrieve all the contacts that have an account with soql query 
How do i find them
Please find below query:

```
Select accountid from contact where accountid in select id from account
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query :

```
[Select accountid from contact where accountid != null];
```

Above query will fetch all contacts which have an account associated with it. Make sure you limit the number of rows fetched.